# Flex 4.5: bin-debug works but bin-release doesn't

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have had this issue countless times with my Flex applications. When I export a release build of my application, it is not able to load my initial configuration files and thus my application can't start. Everything works fine if I run the application from bin-debug folder. For this reason, I often have to deploy my bin-debug folder's contents which are much larger in size.

I am loading those configuration files through URLLoader. All paths being loaded at run-time are relative to the SWF's location. I have tried the compiler option `-use-network=true` but it didn't help. I uploaded bin-release folder to my server and saw the HTTP requests in Firebug but none of those requests is loading the SWZ files or my configuration files. However, when I monitor the requests made by my bin-debug application, it loads all the RSLs (SWF files in bin-debug's case) as well as my config files.

**Edit** The release version doesn't throw any run-time errors.

Comment: What are the initial configuration files?  Where are they located?  Are you sure the config files are in your bin-release folder?  The SWZ files are probably already cached by your Flash Player; so that is why you don't see them loaded.

Comment: Initial configuration files are XML files which contain data used by my application. They are located under bin-release and I give relative paths to them.

Comment: What is returned from the HTTP Requests?  Have you reviewed the packets with something like ServiceCapture or the Flash Builder Network Monitor?

Comment: XML should be returned if the requests are made to the XML paths but I don't see any requests being made in the release version. I use Firebug to monitor the HTTP requests.

Comment: Something is amiss if the URL Requests are not being made.  I'm not sure what that may be, though.

Comment: Do you have any calls to getStackTrace() in your code?

Comment: There are no getStackTrace() calls in my code. Can't say the same about the libraries I'm using. What does that affect?

Comment: In release a call to getStackTrace() will fail (silently because you're in release mode) and is something I've seen periodically when dealing with behavioral differences between debug/release versions. Is the swf making a request for crossdomain.xml? Do you have one? If not, it might be worth adding one (wide open) to see if that changes anything. Obviously, adjusting from there if it does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found out what the problem was. Exporting release build was removing the `[Inject]` metadata tags. I added the compiler argument `-keep-as3-metadata+=Inject` and that fixed it. I found this solution here: https://github.com/robotlegs/robotlegs-framework/wiki/common-problems#wiki-metadata-stripping.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and what helped me was Project->Clean. Just posting in case someone else runs into the problem since it's an easy thing to try.